# neo4j multiple queries cause false results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using `neo4j-javascript-driver` and I have encountered a problem.

I have created a node script that fills the database with `Users` and `Event` (I don't think the script is relevant to the question).

the db is model like that `(u:User)-[:LatestEvent]->(e1:Event)-[:Prev]->(e2:Event)-[:Prev].....`

When trying to run the script to create 1 user with 3 events I do not get the linked list im trying to create, and I think it is because I fire the requests without waiting for the others here is the query:

```
MATCH (user:User {id: {userId})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r:LatestEvent]->(prev:Event)

DELETE r
MERGE (user)-[:LatestEvent]->(event:Event)
ON CREATE SET event={event}

MERGE (user)-[:Posted]->(event)
FOREACH(y IN CASE WHEN prev IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END |  MERGE (event)-[:Prev]->(prev))
WITH DISTINCT event

RETURN DISTINCT properties(event) as event
```

The results in the db are not consistent one time I see 3 events connected to the user with the `LatestEvent` relation and on other this i see 2 or 4.

I think what causes the issue is that when executing this query I do not wait for the previous query to return, but again this something that can happen in the real world..

any solution for that?

Comment: in line 2, shouldn't that be `LatestEvent` with a *t* in the middle? that typo is going to stop you from generating a linked list if it's in your real query.

Comment: Yes thats just a typo on copy

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after playing around with this a bit, I think you can actually pull it off. Your current problem is that you attempt to locate `prev` before you do anything to lock the `:User` node, and thus the linked list. Thus, each of your async queries matches `prev` inside its own transaction. The next line, the `DELETE`, *will* force the queries to serialize, but they have each located and assigned `prev` already. You can get around this by acquiring a write lock on the `:User` node at the absolute start of your query, like so:

```
MATCH (user:User {id: {userId} })
SET user.id = user.id
WITH user
MERGE (user)-[r:LatestEvent]->(prev)
ON CREATE SET prev:Root
DELETE r
CREATE (user)-[:LatestEvent]->(event:Event)
SET event={event}
MERGE (user)-[:Posted]->(event)
MERGE (event) - [:Prev] -> (prev)
RETURN event
```

A couple of changes from your original query:

1) By including `SET user.id = user.id` right at the top, the only thing your queries will do is locate the `:User` before they have to acquire a write lock, which will force them to serialize the rest of the query. Thus, one query will commit and the next query to acquire the lock can read the resulting new `:Event`.

2) Instead of the tortured `OPTIONAL MATCH...FOREACH(CASE...)` logic, this `MERGE`s in a `prev` node, and if there is no previous `:Event`, it will make the node a `:Root` node. This also makes it easier to grab the whole linked list in order by providing a fixed end: `MATCH p = (:User {id: x}) - [:LatestEvent|:Prev*] -> (:Root) RETURN [x IN NODES(p) WHERE x:Event] AS event_list`

3) You are only creating one event, there's no need to apply `DISTINCT` to it. You also won't save much bandwidth by returning `PROPERTIES(event)` instead of `event`, and you will lose some data (labels, internal id, etc.) but you can put back `PROPERTIES()` if you prefer to handle it in Cypher instead of javascript.

You can read more about neo4j isolation [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#transactions-isolation).

Comment: Cool ill try that